# How To update the date in Postgresql db

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to save a date in a postgresql database. Therefore I have written the following code in the controller:

```
def create
    @app_config = AppConfig.new(app_config_params).to_date
    @app_config.save
    respond_with(@app_config)
  end

  private

  def app_config_params
    params.require(:app_config).permit(:freeze_attendance_till)
  end
```

But it is throwing an error like this:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty)
```

So I am unable to save the date in the db. What am I doing wrong?

I created the database using the following code:

```
class CreateAppConfigs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :app_configs do |t|
      t.date :freeze_attendance_till
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you please so us your html page also ?

Comment: Could add at the beginning of your "create" : "raise params.inspect" and edit your question with the response please ?

Comment: Why are you calling `to_date` on the `AppConfig` object? That doesn't seem to be right. Also, you should print out the parameters to see if it is being sent (the error might be elsewhere).

Comment: You need to post your form view that is accepting the date.  If that form view is set correctly then there won't be a need to call "to_date" however if the form view is submitting a string or even a date in a different format you may have to call 'strptime' it